# Regarding UGC service provider TOS clause, how to interpret the assertion that a user "shall defend" the provider?

Tags: legal-terms

Specifically, the user of the User Generated Content platform, according to the services Terms of Service is expected to defend the service in the event that a third party makes a claim involving infringement by the user of the third party's intellectual property or copy right.

How can anyone be expected to go to the defense of a company when they themselves are under threat for misconduct?

This does not seem appropriate.

Can someone help me understand why this terminology is used?

If it matters the company is in the United States.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It means you pay for their lawyers

It's no doubt part of a general indemnity clause; these are pretty common.

The way it works is you do something that puts them at legal hazard, someone sues them, they sue you, you are on the hook for the cost of your defence and the cost of their defence.

Comment: lol, there aren't enough years left of life in most people to extract that much blood. good luck with those clauses then.